# Upgrading from 14.04.2 to 14.04.3 LTS

Tags: 14.04, apt, upgrade, package-management, updates

This is strange, when i try to upgrade to `14.04.3 LTS` from `14.04.2`, it doesn't seem to upgrade with `sudo apt-get upgrade` or `dist-upgrade` or `do-release-upgrade`.

**How else could/should I do it?**

I've tried:

```
alvas@ubi:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty

alvas@ubi:~$ do-release-upgrade
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
No new release found

alvas@ubi:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

alvas@ubi:~$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

---

## EDITED

Adding additional packages didn't work:

```
alvas@ubi:~$ sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-core-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-video-all-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-input-all-lts-vivid libwayland-egl1-mesa-lts-vivid
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package linux-generic-lts-vivid
E: Unable to locate package xserver-xorg-core-lts-vivid
E: Unable to locate package xserver-xorg-lts-vivid
E: Unable to locate package xserver-xorg-video-all-lts-vivid
E: Unable to locate package xserver-xorg-input-all-lts-vivid
E: Unable to locate package libwayland-egl1-mesa-lts-vivid
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-core-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-video-all-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-input-all-lts-vivid libwayland-egl1-mesa-lts-vivid
```

Source:  [Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack)